# Can an exe(converted from a python file) execute batch codes?

Tags: python, batch-file, exe

I have a python script which uses subprocess module to call some batch scripts. This python script does its job of calling batch and doing whats in there. However, when I convert the same .py script into a exe using pyinstaller, the batch does not execute anymore, even when i run the exe file as admin

Comment: This is operating system specific. But you should be aware of the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). It might not be what you believe it is. Without any [MCVE] your question is unclear.

Comment: It's also likely that your current directory when you run the `.exe` is not what it was when tested pre 'conversion'. I would suggest that you rewrite the batch file to use only full paths, or to specifically set the current directory at the outset, then 'convert' it again.

Comment: What do you want from a Windows person. You are running non windows programs. So why tag this for Windows people.

Comment: How is that running for a non windows? Batch file does gets called from python script. I converted the python script into an executable and it no longer calls that batch script

Comment: But why and how did you convert your python script? Why can't you use some `.pyc`  bytecode? And what *exact* error are you getting? **Your question is unclear, and off-topic** without much more details, including some [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Python is never compiled, PyInstaller simply packs your Python.exe with a python bytecode (PYC), and thus the result is the same as if you have done it from a Python console.
Simply do

```py
from os import system
system("call foo.bat")
```